# Why is there no conditional statements in the last line of this code?

Tags: haskell

In the following code you have to write a function to check if a list is sorted or not.

```
isOrd :: [Int] -> Bool
isOrd [] = True
isOrd [_] = True
isOrd (x:y:xs) = x<=y && isOrd (y:xs)
```

I would like to know why there is no need to write if/then/else or case for the last line? Why don't we need to check if it's `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 8):

What if/then/else would you propose writing? The one I would imagine would look something like this:

```
isOrd (x:y:xs) = if x<=y && isOrd (y:xs)
                 then True
                 else False
```

But we know that `if x then True else False` is always just a particularly long-winded way to write `x`. So there's not really any need for a specific conditional branch here: we can just return the condition itself.

Comment: To say it another way: True and False are real values that can be passed around like any other value. You aren't restricted to using them as the condition in an `if`.

Comment: for imperative thinking, I'd expect something like, `if not ( x<=y ) then False else  isOrd (y:xs)`.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: `if b then True else False` is equivalent to `case b of { True -> True; False -> False }`. Given some Boolean `b`, it produces a `Bool` that’s identical to `b` in every way, just like `id b`.

Answer (score 5):

That is checked by the [**`(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-38--38-) function: if the left operand is `False`, it returns `False`. If the left operand is `True`, it returns the right operand.

Indeed, the function is [implemented as <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Classes.html#line-232):

> ```
> (&&)                    :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
> True  && x              =  x
> False && _              =  False
> ```

It thus will check the first operand, and based on that either return `False`, or recurse on the rest of the function.

Comment: That old school spacing is ridonkulous

Comment: @Iceland_jack: I agree, it was IIRC not the advised way to format code, but this is how it was written in the source code :s.

Comment: It's has an undeniable retro feel though

Comment: @Iceland_jack: yes, iirc this was once how it was supposed to be written, but it looks "ugly".

Answer (score 3):

> like why we don't need to check if it's True or False?

Because the function's output type is `Bool` and it is enough for us just return `Bool` as **amalloy** mentioned.

So, firstly we said that empty list and list with one element are sorted lists. Then we said: "check if the first element of the list is less or equal then the second. If it isn't then return `False`. If it is then check if the same list without the first element is sorted". And this is enough to return the right `Bool` for all input lists.